# Routing http request to WSGI app (Flask + Apache)

Tags: python-2.7, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

My Flask based web app is ready to go, and I'm currently connecting it up to Apache 2.2.

When I start Apache serving the app from root

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/path/to/script.wsgi
```

everything works as expected. However, I want to serve multiple versions of the WSGI script that will connect to different databases, which means I need to serve each with a unique alias:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /firstscript /var/www/path/to/first/script.wsgi
...
WSGIScriptAlias /secondscript /var/www/path/to/second/script.wsgi
```

When I try to access one of these:

```
www.example.com/firstscript
```

the WSGI app loads, but all http requests are still routed to the root. What is the best way for me to reroute all http requests to my WSGI app? Here is my apache config:

```
WSGIPythonHome /usr
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/path/to/first
<VirtualHost *>
    WSGIDaemonProcess firstscript user=apache group=apache  threads=5 python-path=/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIScriptAlias /firstscript /var/www/path/to/first/script.wsgi                                              

    <Directory /var/www/path/to/first>                                                                  
        WSGIProcessGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT:

I've followed the (much appreciated) recommendations from @grahamdumpleton, which have helped me to clean up my Apache configs, but my http requests continue to be routed to the Apache server's root, rather than the WSGI app. Here's my current config:

```
WSGIPythonHome /usr
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/path/to/first
<VirtualHost *>
    WSGIDaemonProcess firstscript threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /firstscript /var/www/path/to/first/script.wsgi process-group=firstscript application-group=%{GLOBAL}                                              

    <Directory /var/www/path/to/first>
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also tried adding a process group under the directory tag: `WSGIProcessGroup firstscript`, which also failed to have any impact.

Answer (score 1):

The following should be removed for a start:

```
WSGIProcessGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

This is causing everything to be handled in the same Python interpreter, and not even in the daemon process group, so likely they are interfering with each other.

Using:

```
python-path=/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

is also wrong. You don't need that when using system Python, and `python-path` is wrong way of referring to a virtual environment anyway.

Finally you don't need:

```
user=apache group=apache
```

either as defaults to using the Apache user already.

That first change may be enough to get it working as each application will now run in a separate sub interpreter of the daemon process group.

If that doesn't work, you should create more than one daemon process group and delegate each to a separate daemon process group.

That would be done using:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess firstscript threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /firstscript /var/www/path/to/first/script.wsgi process-group=firstscript application-group=%{GLOBAL}

WSGIDaemonProcess secondscript threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /secondscript /var/www/path/to/second/script.wsgi process-group=secondscript application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits! I've made your recommended changes, but my http requests are still routed to the web server's root instead of the WSGI app. I've edited my question so you can see the new configs! Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: That is most like because you haven't added ``ServerName`` directive with your hostname. If there is a prior ``VirtualHost``, it will use that as fallback when can't match based on hostname. Also, you don't need ``WSGIPythonHome`` directive when using system Python. And, generally you would use ``*:80`` in ``VirtualHost`` and not just ``*``.